# How to prevent PHP variables from showing up on HTML

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Here's what im trying to do, when you click the "Open" Button, the variable $a then is placed on the back of the a href, however it just keeps showing up on the page, anybody know how to prevent this and to put the $a variable at the end of the a href link? thanks

```
?>
<table>
<tr>
<th>Action</th>
<th>Payout</th>
<th>Description</th>
<th>Offer Name</th>
<th>Action</th>
</tr>
</table>
<?php
$offername= "SELECT * FROM offers WHERE active = 1";
$exec= $mysqli->query($offername);
if (mysqli_num_rows($exec) == 0){
    echo "No Offers Yet";
}else{
   while ($array=mysqli_fetch_row($exec)){
     $a=$array[3];
     $x=$array[0];
     $y=$array[1];
     $z=$array[2];
  echo " <tr>\n " .
        " <td>$z</td>\n" .
        " <td>$y</td>\n" .

        " <td>$x</td>\n" .

        " <td><a href=\"click.php?id=$a\">Open</a></td>\n";
}}

?>
```

Comment: You've asked nine questions and accepted no answers. Perhaps accepting some helpful answers would help elicit some better responses to your question.

Comment: What keeps showing up on the page? What output does the code above produce?

Comment: @zeantsoi, thank you for this insight.  I was just about to provide an answer, but won't waste my time now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are printing $a in your string rather than concatenating it's value to what you want to echo. Consider:

```
echo " <tr>\n " .
        " <td>".$z."</td>\n" .
        " <td>".$y."</td>\n" .

        " <td>".$x."</td>\n" .

        " <td><a href=\"click.php?id=".$a."\">Open</a></td>\n";
```

Comment: You don't necessarily have to concatenate `"<td>$z</td>\n"` because PHP will still read the $z variable it's only needed with the escaped quotes in the OP's question. However it better to do is the way you described you get into less trouble that way...thats the way I do it anyway. Just wanted to add 2 more cents for what its worth.

Answer (score 2):

You could try double quoting the variables. What every one said is important and good practice. But lets not forget that every one was once new to php and stackoverflow.

```
echo "<td><a href=\"click.php?id=".$a."\">Open</a></td>\n";
```

I think the problem may have been coming from the fact that you were already escaping the quotes here

```
href=\"...
```

So the parser was treating everything within as text and ignored the "$a". Let me know if that helps.